# Is the scene with Romilly different between the IMAX and DVD/BluRay releases of Interstellar?

Tags: interstellar, alternate-version, imax

I originally saw the UK IMAX release of Interstellar and recently saw the BluRay version of it and, did I dream this:

When Cooper et al. return from Millers planet (3 hours their time, 23 years Endurance time) they enter the spaceship and there's an older Romilly waiting for them at the door... This is what happened on the BluRay version I saw.

I seem to remember in the Cinema IMAX version ...
They return to the ship and a looks like 'no one's home'. After a bit of exploration they find a 'garden' wrapped in plastic sheeting (similar to that of the martian) where they find a traumatised Romilly cowering amongst the plants.

Did that happen or did I dream it?

If it happened then it would go a long way towards answering this question:
[How did Romilly survive 23 years on the Endurance?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35403/how-did-romilly-survive-23-years-on-the-endurance)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, I am sure **that did *not* happen in *any* version of the film**. But I can't do more than offer you my word of having seen it in the cinema twice and never remembering such a scene. Neither is it elaborated to exist in any of the various behind-the-scenes materials that I extensively watched, too.

But another reason that adds to being sure this never happened in *Interstellar* is that I don't think you dreamed this either. What I think you actually do is **conflating this with a different movie, [*Mission to Mars*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0183523/)**. In this film there is also a crew returning to a supposedly desolate former camp on Mars, only to find a surviving (and slightly confused/traumatized) crew member (Don Cheadle with a beard not too dissimilar to old Romilly's), who sustained himself with a garden under a plastic-wrap greenhouse. Add to this the recent release of the already mentioned *The Martian* also set on Mars (and which with *Gravity* and *Interstellar* adds into somewhat of a triumvirate of "realistic" space films lately, that people like to compare with each other), and the confusion of these two superficially similar scenes is understandable.

Comment: If you then mix in the fact that they are basically finding Mark Whatney later in *Interstellar*, who is slightly traumatized, too, [the confusion this might cause is unimaginable](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/51137/49). ;-) (They should have cast Sandra Bullock as Amelia Brand.)