# Why does the Endurance rotate in Interstellar?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

In the 2014 film [Interstellar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film)), why does the spacecraft Endurance spin? I think it really has to do something with physics?

[image]

Comment: [Everything's better with spinning](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EverythingsBetterWithSpinning#!) (TV Tropes link).

Comment: I bet I know [what kind of music they have in the lifts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGNiXGX2nLU).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### It rotates to create artificial gravity

A [rotating space station is a known concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_wheel_space_station) (apparently [Tsiolkovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konstantin_Tsiolkovsky) thought about it in the very beginning of 20th century). It uses the rotation to induce a centripetal (acting towards the centre) acceleration on the people inside.

In order for a body to stay in motion with constant speed in a circular path with radius R, it must have an [acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_acceleration) equal to the square of its linear speed divided by the radius R (or the square of its angular speed multiplied by the radius).

This acceleration is actually caused by the normal force exerted by the floor of the station on the people - the people inside would be hurled into space, but the floor keeps them in the circular path, so they feel an acceleration which is similar to the acceleration due to gravity.

[image]
 <sub>From the [*Wired* article](https://www.wired.com/2014/10/physics-spinning-spacecraft-interstellar/)</sub>

As to why it's needed at all - remember that *Endurance* is not a fast flier. It's supposed to be in space for a long time ([Romilly spent 23 years there](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/35403/44222)), and being subjected to weightlessness for a long time [bone decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceflight_osteopenia) occurs. The simplest solution is to take gravity with you, and this is a plausible way to do that (though we are yet to see any such stations in real life).

- [Read about various ways of achieving artificial gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_gravity) (hat tip to Johnny Bones)
- [Watch my professor explain centipetal force in PHYS 101](https://youtu.be/MyzZ6JyxtP4?t=11m50s);

  Might want to revisit [uniform circular motion](https://youtu.be/d32AQF1TM18?t=4m0s) too.
- [There's a nice Wired article about it.](https://www.wired.com/2014/10/physics-spinning-spacecraft-interstellar/)
- See also [Larry Niven's *Ringworld*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringworld) which applies this concept to a whole world.
- [*2001: A Space Odyssey*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_One#Centrifuge) and [*The Martian* (*Wired* article again :D)](https://www.wired.com/2015/08/spinning-spacecraft-martian-work/) used this for their respective space ships.

Comment: was just about to comment on your definition of centripetal... then you changed it entirely ;) Most people think it's centrifugal force... but it's not, it's centripetal.

Comment: I _could_ say there's a centrifugal force (equal to inertia) which is trying to hurl people into space, but I find this one more intuitive.

Comment: I'd compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force but tbh, math is not my strong point, I just recall my physics professor telling me which was which & why. (tbh, for the purposes of a movie plot & why a space station is set to spin, the distinction is not really all that important ;)

Comment: I'd add this for extra weight (pardon the pun).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_gravity

Comment: Cheers, @JohnnyBones ;)

Comment: Relevant XKCD: https://xkcd.com/123/

Comment: You said yourself that "centripetal" means "towards the centre". If the dominant force acted towards the centre, they'd… move towards the centre. You do mean "centrifugal", which means "fleeing the centre". In any normal conversation, the terms mean exactly what they say. Gravity is similarly a fictional force, but no-one says it doesn't exist.

Comment: @PatrickStevens It's not exactly like that. They always have a velocity that is perpendicular to the radius of the space station. The acceleration that acts on them is only enough to keep that velocity always perpendicular (i.e. tangential to their path, but not enough to move them towards the centre. I don't like centrifugal force because there's no fundamental force that's causing it; one the other hand, gravity is very real because it's one of the [4 fundamental forces of nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction).

Comment: @Mark I know centrifugal force is sometimes legitimately used. Problem is, I didn't take the course that explains it yet :D I guess I can update this answer next semester.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Well, as long as you also never refer to Coriolis force or to the force that presses you back when you accelerate, I suppose it's consistent. But words are there to get people to understand you. A minor technical detail like "a tomato is not a vegetable" or "centrifugal force doesn't exist" just hinders conversation in many cases. Why would you not take the reference frame of the spaceship, anyway? It's the only interesting thing in that region of space.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I imagine it's a bit more intuitive to deal with an inertial frame of reference. This was we can extend the concept used in spinning a weight on rope, the banking turn, etc., to space. And it works without additional assumptions, which I think only helps the case.